# Getting Error :-ValueError: format number 1 of "b'Feb 1978, 2, 1975 Total time of visit (in minutes):\n'" is not recognized

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a df into datatime using formula below:

```
output_final_date['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(output_final_date[['Year','Month','Day']].astype(str),format='%Y%m%d%')
```

But I am getting the  error:

> ValueError: format number 1 of "b'Feb 1978, 2, 1975 Total time of visit (in minutes):\n'" is not recognized

No idea from where this error is coming.

My df is having data as :

```
output_final_date.dtypes
Year     int32
Month    int32
Day      int32
dtype: object

output_final_date.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 481 entries, 0 to 480
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Year     481 non-null int32
Month    481 non-null int32
Day      481 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(3)
```

Comment: Can you share your input data ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think `.astype` and `format` should be removed and added `errors='coerce'` for convert problematic non datetimes values to missing values, `NaT`:

```
output_final_date['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(output_final_date[['Year','Month','Day']], errors='coerce')
```